# Top 10 of total amount paid aggregated by provider, partitioned by state - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, common-table-expression

I have a database of medicare data with three tables: provider metadata (doctor's unique number, name, city, state, credentials, etc); hcpcs metadata (code, description, if it's for drugs or not); provider_services (doctor's unique number, hcpcs code, number of services completed by that doctor, average cost)

I'm *trying* to get the top 10 payments by state, aggregated by provider. However I'm running into an issue where 1) I can't figure out how to rank by the total payment and 2) I can't figure out how to aggregate the providers. Here's the best query I've gotten so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT p.npi,
          p.nppes_provider_last_org_name AS last_name, 
          p.nppes_provider_first_name AS first_name, 
          p.nppes_provider_city AS city,
          p.nppes_provider_state AS state,
          (ps.average_medicare_payment_amt * ps.line_srvc_cnt) AS total_amount,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.nppes_provider_state ORDER BY ps.average_medicare_payment_amt desc) AS rank
   FROM provider_services ps
   JOIN provider p ON ps.npi = p.npi
) t
WHERE rank <= 10
GROUP BY t.last_name, t.npi, t.first_name, t.city, t.state, t.total_amount, t.rank
ORDER BY state ASC;
```

This results in something like:

```
| LAST | FIRST| STATE | TOTAL | RANK |  
|-------|------|----|---------|---|   
| DOE   | JANE | AK | 3000.41 | 10|   
| SMITH | JOHN | AK | 6000.98 | 7 |   
| COLE  | ANN  | AK | 1000    | 4 |   
| SMITH | JOHN | AK | 1560.32 | 1 |
```

So my issues are 1. the providers aren't aggregating (John Smith with the same unique number showing up multiple times) and 2. I can only get it to compile with that `average_payment_amt` and not `total_amt` so the rankings are really screwed up.

Comment: You should show the results that you want.  Your question is not totally clear.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following adjustments:

- Avoid ever using `SELECT *` in aggregate queries with `GROUP BY`. It is a wonder this query was allowed in PostgreSQL without error but such use of `SELECT *` may be shorthand for all columns specified in `GROUP BY`.
- Use calculated expression for *total_amount* in the window function's `ORDER BY` clause.
- Apply an aggregation function like `SUM` on your *total_amount* and do not include it as grouping column. In fact, you do not mention *how* you want to aggregate by *provider*.
- Rank based on state throws off aggregation based on different column: *provider*. Right now it appears you want to use *rank* only for filtering records and not display.

Below achieves the following:

> Sums total payment amounts by provider for the top 10 payment amounts per state.

```
SELECT t.npi, t.last_name, t.first_name, t.city, t.state,
       SUM(t.total_amount) AS total_amount
FROM (
   SELECT p.npi,
          p.nppes_provider_last_org_name AS last_name, 
          p.nppes_provider_first_name AS first_name, 
          p.nppes_provider_city AS city,
          p.nppes_provider_state AS state,
          (ps.average_medicare_payment_amt * ps.line_srvc_cnt) AS total_amount,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.nppes_provider_state 
                       ORDER BY ps.average_medicare_payment_amt * ps.line_srvc_cnt DESC) AS rank
   FROM provider_services ps
   JOIN provider p ON ps.npi = p.npi
) t
WHERE rank <= 10
GROUP BY t.npi, t.last_name, t.first_name, t.city, t.state
ORDER BY t.state ASC;
```

---

Now, below achieves the following if this is your intention:

> Displays records of top 10 payments per state in state and rank order (where providers can repeat if they ranked multiple times within or between states).

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
   SELECT p.npi,
          p.nppes_provider_last_org_name AS last_name, 
          p.nppes_provider_first_name AS first_name, 
          p.nppes_provider_city AS city,
          p.nppes_provider_state AS state,
          (ps.average_medicare_payment_amt * ps.line_srvc_cnt) AS total_amount,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.nppes_provider_state 
                       ORDER BY ps.average_medicare_payment_amt * ps.line_srvc_cnt DESC) AS rank
   FROM provider_services ps
   JOIN provider p ON ps.npi = p.npi
) t
WHERE rank <= 10
ORDER BY t.state, t.rank;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you actually want to aggregate in the subquery and rank by the total amount:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT p.npi,
             p.nppes_provider_last_org_name AS last_name, 
             p.nppes_provider_first_name AS first_name, 
             p.nppes_provider_state AS state,
             SUM(ps.average_medicare_payment_amt * ps.line_srvc_cnt) AS total_amount,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.nppes_provider_state ORDER BY SUM(ps.average_medicare_payment_amt * ps.line_srvc_cnt) DESC) as rnk
      FROM provider_services ps JOIN
           provider p
           ON ps.npi = p.npi
      ) t
WHERE rnk <= 10
ORDER BY state ASC, total_amount DESC;
```